# Is anonymous function in Vue Template a performance killer?

Tags: vue.js, templates, anonymous-function, emit

I have following setup:

In Child component:

```
 <template>
   <div @click="clickHandler">
   </div>
 </template>
 <script>
    ...
    clickHandler() { 
     this.$emit('emittedFunction', someInfo, otherInfo)
    }
 </script>
```

In Parent component:

```
<template> 
  <child-component 
    v-for="index in 10"
    @emittedFunction="(someInfo, otherInfo) => someFunction(index, someInfo, otherInfo)"/>     
 </template>
 <script>
    ...
    someFunction(index, someInfo, otherInfo) { 
     do stuff 
    }
 </script>
```

This code works perfectly fine. To my question though: A friend of mine saw this code snippet and remarked in comments, that "anonymous functions in Vue Templates are a performance killer" and I should do it another way...he obviously didn't explain how. 
I can't find anything on this topic in vue documentation or stack overflow. I also don't understand why would this kind of code 'kill' performance? 
Is he right? If yes, why? If not, why not? Is there a way to refactor my code, if it's actually bad?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is referring to the fact that templates are compiled to render functions, which are run on each re-render.

The problem they are referring to is that assigning an anonymous function has a small overhead due to handler being different in each render, meaning Vue can't re-use the hander and causes it to re-render the node with the listener.

This could introduce a performance issue indeed, but it is unlikely you will run into or write a code that's slow because of this. More often than not if your component is re-rendering that frequently that the overhead compounds to be noticeable, that means you should fix the re-rendering trigger rather than this.

So I wouldn't go as far as to say its "a performance killer", but more like an "optimization opportunity".

To be on the safe side, you could refactor it using closures, something like this:

```
<template> 
<child-component 
  v-for="index in 10"
  @emittedFunction="someFunction(index)(someInfo, otherInfo)"
/>     
</template>

<script>
   ...
   someFunction(index) { 
    return (someInfo, otherInfo) => {
      // this is a closure, you have access to the index.
    };
   }
</script>
```

While this looks weird, it doesn't create a new function on each render, it only creates a new function when the event is emitted and it is not tied to rendering.

Comment: Wouldn't writing it that way still require Vue to generate an internal wrapper function for each node, so effectively you're back where you started?

Comment: I'm not sure on how Vue does it exactly, but if you take a look at the `update-listeners.js` helper in the Vue source. It creates a special `invoker` object which acts as the dispatcher for the handlers, for IIFE like the one in the snippet above it just adds it to the invoker `fns` and if it actually changes, it will remove it without re-rendering the node, otherwise it does a simple `===` to check if the previous handler is equal to the new one.

Comment: I think the more pertinent portion of the source is https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/2c6a827b39d824f87239dc124a0e3f0895d43247/src/compiler/codegen/events.js#L96, which generates the relevant section of the `render` function based on the string value parsed from a `v-on` attribute. Vue itself needs to create a wrapper function so that it can hold `index` in a closure and that function will need recreating every time the component is rendered to ensure it is referencing the latest value of `index`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answers!! This topic seems to have more complexity that I anticipated, though. 
The emit event in the child component, will be emitted very very often. My someFunction in the parent component will change some values, which are sent as props back to the child component, so the child component with number "index" will rerender at that point. But I assume that the Parent component still will not completely rerender at that point?

Is there a way to find out if there is a performance impact, if I for example emit "emittedFunction" like 200 times per minute?