# Vue inline click event `this` is undefined

Tags: vue.js

i'm getting an error in the below code saying `this` is undefined.

```js
<div class="location-list__item" v-for="(value, key) in locations.data">
    <div class="location-list__item--text"
         :class="{ selected: selected === key }"
         @click="() => { this.selected = key; this.manageSurrounding = false }">
        <i class="fas fa-compass"></i> {{ value.name }}
        <span v-if="value.changed" class="has-text-danger"> Changed</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

However if I change this line:

`@click="() => { this.selected = key; this.manageSurrounding = false }"`

to this

`@click="selected = key"`

It works fine, however I need to change `manageSurrounding` at the same time and I don't want to create a method for such a simple thing.

Comment: `this` is not in template scope, just use: `@click="() => { selected = key; manageSurrounding = false }"`

Comment: @ZedHome This doesn't work at all, already tried

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 5):

You can do multiple assignments by using semicolon like the above statement which you have written.

```html
<div class="location-list__item" v-for="(value, key) in locations.data">
    <div class="location-list__item--text"
         :class="{ selected: selected === key }"
         @click="selected = key;manageSurrounding = false">        # Like this
        <i class="fas fa-compass"></i> {{ value.name }}
        <span v-if="value.changed" class="has-text-danger"> Changed</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: > Statements are not allowed in Vue expressions

Comment: @MartynBall That's not true. Why do you think that? See [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yLeJLWr) of the answer above.

Comment: @tony19 that's the error I get when I attempt to do what you say

Comment: @MartynBall Where are you seeing the error? If it's [Webstorm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36561), that's not actually a real error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a anonymous function like,

```
<div onclick="return function()

 { selected = key; manageSurrounding = false }'

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method and put in the update lines, you are better off on the long run, if your list is changing/reordering/re-rendering often.

It’s an optimization opportunity, so don’t try to force it in just because it seems small. Have a look at this answer: [anonymus function in template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58923214)